# How to use a remote folder for Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

On Thunderbird, I would like to use a remote folder located on my cloud instead of the local folder.

Is there any addon that could make it possible ?

Comment: What have you tried? We don't recommend software here.

Comment: Use an IMAP mail server then your mails will be always on the server/in the cloud so that you can access them from multiple computers. The local data is then just a cache.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the Thunderbird profile folder to the cloud, as long as it is
addressable on your devices.
Thunderbird is set to point to that location with the help of its Profile Manager,
called by the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -profilemanager
```

You may also start TB with command line arguments that specify the profile,
using the `-profile "path"` (or `-P "path"`) command line argument to specify the
location of the profile, regardless of whether the Profile Manager knows about that
profile's existence.

A third method is just moving the mail folders to another location, by
using menu *Tools > Account Settings*, click "Local Folders" on the left pane,
then under "Local directory" click on the "Browse..." button to select the folder
and click the "OK" button.

Comment: Note that it is a bad idea to use the same folder from more than one device at the same time.

Comment: A profile on a cloud device is totally unsupported.  You risk your data, for what?

Comment: But you can keep your profile on local disk and point an ACCOUNT to a different folder, for example in the cloud.  Again, you may encounter corruption later. AND don't dare share that folder in the cloud with someone running Thunderbird on another computer.